# Add Help File to Module

Tags: powershell

I've created some Modules and want to add some `Get-Help` files to give a little subscription or tutorial for my coworkers.

I've added the specific help-files in the right Directory-Folder and covert the files in the right Unicode Format like the description on the MSDN site.

Now I give the cmd `Get-Help ModuleName` but nothing loads except the normal help which is given from Powershell?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share what you've tried so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

One way is to write the help inside the module file directly

```
<# 
 .Synopsis
  Whatever you want to display.

 .Description
  A description for the same.

 .Parameter Start
  Whatever Parameter start you want .

 .Parameter End
  Whatever Parameter end you want to display.

 .Example
   # Show an example below.
   Example of the function
#>
```

Other ways are : Listed

**[HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878343(v=vs.85).aspx) and [External Help for PS Modules](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/create-external-help-powershell-module-functions,1-3667.html)**

Hope it helps.